# Why were Lucy and Rajesh not developed as a couple?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Was Lucy (Kate Micucci) ever intended to become a long-term cast member in the Big Bang Theory?  She seems to me to be a more interesting character than Emily, who replaced her as Raj's girlfriend.  Have the producers ever commented on why she was written out?

Comment: I always felt they never knew what to do with her character as time went on.

Comment: Because the actress wasn't funny. Because the two actors had no chemistry between them. Because she was not supersmart unlike Amy, or sweet and sexy-looking like Benedette. She had nothing going for her, the writers were uninspired.... because American boys/men  like to see "hot" actresses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The makers (producers) of the big bang theory sign new actors on as 'GUEST APPEARANCE/RECURRING' roles and only if they are have good skills and are liked by the audience, they are converted into 'REGULAR' roles.

So initially only Sheldon, Raj, Penny, Leonard and Howard were the perms. The rest were temps. The family members, co-workers, Stuart, etc were all on recurring basis.

Maybe the writers saw that her character was not going anywere and decided to move on with her.

But she still keeps comming to the series like in [Season 10](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Lucy):

> She reappears in "The Emotion Detection Automation", along with Emily (season 5), Emily and Claire to talk about why she ended things with Raj. She is also the only one who's actually sympathetic to Raj about his failed love life.

I honestly felt that she wasn't funny at all, and didn't bring anything more to the series.

Also that's kind of Raj thing in the series, he is always trying to find a woman to be in with love with, but always screws up, lose her and go after another.